# Problem with printing character with pointer

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am beginner. I am learning C. I learnt about pointers through [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com). I then thought to create an array of string. So, I created a program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    char b[] = "Hi", *a;
    a = &b[0];
    printf("%s", a);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

When I am getting the whole word here. a is pointing to `H` of Hi. So, is there any mistake in the code?

Comment: Notice that the types in your code match the line `char *ptr2 = a;      // Points to the 'H' of "Hello world"`. Remove the `&` and be done.

Comment: Please not that I had changed the question

Comment: Please **do not** change the question after you've gotten an answer.

Comment: I'm sorry. Actually, when I clicked on Ask question again, I got a message showing that you've reached your limit.

Comment: And the title is *still* wrong.

Comment: Thanks for reminding

Comment: C doesn't have strings.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character array has type `char *` but when you do `a = &b` the `b` is interpreted as of type `char (*)[]`. So remove `&`  or write it as `a = &b[0]`.

Now that you have changed it to `a = &b[0]` - the `printf` statement prints the entire string i.e. `"Hi"` even when `a` is pointing to the first element of the array `b` as `%s` format specifier prints the entire string taking a character pointer to some string as an argument.

Plus `conio.h` is not a part of the standard compiler - you should stop using **Turbo**.

Comment: Please not that I had changed this question.

Comment: @user9953286 Updated my answer.

Comment: I use CodeBlocks

Comment: Please answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53853518/different-output-for-same-type-of-input-in-c?noredirect=1